# Test data directory with jUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm writing some jUnit tests that depend on data files.  Where should those data files go? And how would I (in the jUnit tests) get the location of that directory?

In Python, I would use something similar to:

```
datadir = os.dirname(__file__) + "/data/"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kind of depends on what you're using the data files for, but in general, just create a package and make sure it's on your classpath. To load a properties file from the "data" package, add a "MyData.props" file and you can use load a properties file like:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/data/MyData.props");
```

Again, not exactly sure if this answers your question since I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but I hope it helps a little.

Answer (score 2):

Keep your test data close to your test classes (same package). As todd.run suggested, use `getResourceAsStream()` to access your data files.